# How to isolate values from a list in Python?

Tags: python, list, methods

I have a few lists I'm trying to investigate.I'm stuck at some point:

```
D = [1, 1, 1, 2, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 1]
```

Let's say this is the list. I need to isolate a new list from the list D.We can say I want to filter those "1"'s; but I couldn't manage it.

If I use "index" method like:

```
D = [1, 1, 1, 2, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 1]

E = []

for i in D:
    if not i == 1:
        E.append(D.index(i))

print(E)
```

The output is: [3, 4, 10, 3].What I need is [3, 4, 10, 11].Since values are at D[3] and D[11] are the same, python does not allow me to get the second one.How can I solve this?

Your help is highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: You seem to want to make a list of the indexes of the non-1 values, not the values themselves, but you don't actually say that in the question. Try researching the enumerate function and looping over enumerate (D)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write this program in many ways. I will try to adapt your example with minimal changes first:

```
D = [1, 1, 1, 2, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 1]

E = []

for i in range(len(D)):
    if D[i] != 1:
        E.append(i)

print(E)
```

However, there is also a shorter/simpler one-line solution:

```
D = [1, 1, 1, 2, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 1]
E = [i for i in range(len(D)) if D[i]!=1]
print(E)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a conditional list comprehension to [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) the values in `D` and get the index locations of those values that match your condition.

```
>>> [idx for idx, val in enumerate(D) if val != 1]
[3, 4, 10, 11]
```

Note that you can also use [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) to create a generator of the values at those index locations.

```
>>> list(filter(lambda val: val != 1, D))
[2, 5, 3, 2]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the `index` function indeed always returns the first occurence. From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists):

> **list.index(x[, start[, end]])**
>
> Return zero-based index in the list of the first item whose value is equal to x. Raises a ValueError if there is no such item.
>
> ...

We can use [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) and combine this with [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) to get what you want:

```
[index for index, value in enumerate(D) if value != 1]
# [3, 4, 10, 11]
```

Comment: Thanks very much ;)